# PHP related queries

Tags: php, forms

I recently started learning PHP and while I was practicing form handling the browser is displaying my code and not executing it. I added the following line in the following files.

-->HTTPD - LoadModule php5_module "C:\xampp\php"\php7apache2_4.dll"

--> .httaccess - AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .htm .HTML (I am using PHP 7.4.3)

Below is my code:

index.html

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="welcome.php" method="post">
<?PHP echo "Welcome!" ?>
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

welcome.php file:

```
<html>
<body>

Welcome <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?><br>
Your email address is: <?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your form action is posting to index1.php --> `<form action="index1.php" method="post">` yet you call your `$_POST["name"]` on `welcome.php` are you redirecting a global post variable to your welcome page that sends the key value of `$_POST['name']` and `$_POST['email'']`?

Comment: Are you trying to make a login system?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your forms action POST method is sending to a different page than the one you are trying to receive and parse information on.

According to your question, you are calling the following code on `welcome.php`:

```
Welcome <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?><br>
Your email address is: <?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?>
```

However your form action on `index.php` is set to `index1.php`.

```
<form action="index1.php" method="post">
```

Set your action to `welcome.php` directory and it should work.

```
<form action="welcome.php" method="post">
```

You can make sure by `print_r($_POST)` or `var_dump($_POST)` on your `welcome.php` page to make sure that post data is making it.

***NOTE:*** As a beginner, make sure to always sanitize your users input, research sanitizing and validating inputs to make sure your code is not open to attacks. It's much better to learn this early on.

Comment: I tried changing the file name but it still doesn't work. I also tried a simple PHP code in HTML but it won't execute the code. It looks like the PHP code id being commented.

Comment: Please update your question's code with the new code you are using